# Update and read fast a list in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a webpart with this behaviour:

- When it loads, it reads a Sharepoint list, and then shows a popup message.
- When I accept the message, then the Webpart updates the list.

To read the value I have a function inside CreateChildControls

```
protected override void CreateChildControls() {
readList()
... 
otherStuff
}
```

and to save the value I have a hiddenField, that executes the save function when changes the value:

```
hiddenField.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(functionThatSavesTheValue);
```

Then when the user accept the message of the popup, I change the value of the hiddenField via javascript, to execute the functionThatSavesTheValue

```
button.value = '1' + button.value;
```

Since here, all works fine.

The problem is if I reload the page just after push the button.

In that case, the function that reads the list executes before the function that saves the value, and I get wrong values. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CreateChildControls to initialize your controls and read the list in OnPreRender.

Comment: Didn't work. Finally we change the behaviour of the webpart. Thanks